# Is there a way to close a workbook using xlrd

Tags: python, xlrd

I am using the function open_workbook() to open an excel file. But I cannot find any function to close the file later in the xlrd module. Is there a way to close the xls file using xlrd?
Or is not required at all?

Comment: It's been a couple years since I used xlrd, but I think it takes care of closing the file for you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Digging into the [mailing list archive](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&pli=1#!searchin/python-excel/close/python-excel/U2mKQkfLkGQ/ogym1iiW_R4J), it seems that the file object is closed directly by the constructor, so you don't need to close it explicitly.

Comment: Note if you use on_demand=True the file is _not_ closed, even if the workbook is collected. This is documented in the xlrd comments. You should be careful to call release_resources() before letting the workbook go away.

Answer (score 6):

The open_workbook calls the release_resources ( which closes the mmaped file ) before returning.